# Check exit status of `execute_process` in cmake

Tags: cmake

In my cmake file i run a command with `execute_process`. And i want to check if it failed. It doesn't print anything to `stderr`.

So far I have been using a bash script that runs the command and then checks the exit status with `$? == 1`.

Is there a way to do something similar with cmake?

```
execute_process(COMMAND "runThis")
if("{$?}" EQUAL 1)
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Bad exit status")
endif()
```

I use cmake 3.12.1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may find exit status of the executing process by using `RESULT_VARIABLE` option for `execute_process` invocation. From option's [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/execute_process.html):

> The variable will be set to contain the result of running the processes. This will be an integer return code from the last child or a string describing an error condition.

Example:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "runThis" RESULT_VARIABLE ret)
if(ret EQUAL "1")
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Bad exit status")
endif()
```

Comment: As per @caldfir's answer `if(ret AND NOT ret EQUAL 0)`.

Answer (score 10):

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) indicates that `RESULT_VARIABLE` may be used to check the status of `execute_process`. Since it may contain *either* a string *or* an exit-code, both should be considered when checking for errors.

Here is an example putting that into practice:

```
# good
execute_process(
  COMMAND cmake --version
  RESULT_VARIABLE STATUS
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT1 
  ERROR_QUIET )
if(STATUS AND NOT STATUS EQUAL 0)
  message(STATUS "FAILED: ${STATUS}")
else()
  message(STATUS "SUCCESS: ${OUTPUT1}")
endif()

# nonzero exit code
execute_process(
  COMMAND cmake -G xxxx
  RESULT_VARIABLE STATUS
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT2 
  ERROR_QUIET )
if(STATUS AND NOT STATUS EQUAL 0)
  message(STATUS "FAILED: ${STATUS}")
else()
  message(STATUS "SUCCESS: ${OUTPUT2}")
endif()

# bad command
execute_process(
  COMMAND xxxx
  RESULT_VARIABLE STATUS
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT3 
  ERROR_QUIET )
if(STATUS AND NOT STATUS EQUAL 0)
  message(STATUS "FAILED: ${STATUS}")
else()
  message(STATUS "SUCCESS: ${OUTPUT3}")
endif()
```

output:

```
SUCCESS: cmake version 3.18.0-rc3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

FAILED: 1
FAILED: The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 8):

cmake execute_process, exit on error

since cmake 3.19 we have the option [COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/execute-proces-interaction-between-command-error-is-fatal-and-timeout/2303)

```
execute_process(COMMAND echo hello COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY)
```